# c++ Getting an error "Run-Time check failure #2 - stack around variable sub was corrupted"

Tags: c++

I could use help with solving this problem, looked online and saw that many problems were due to the size of the array in other programmer's programs. So I tried changing numbers affecting the array "sub" and still haven't found a solution.  All instances of sub in my program are included below.

```
int sub[9]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

          for(int i=0;i<=8;i++)
          {
            if(sub[i]>0)
            {

                if(one==sub[i]&one>0&one<200)
                {
                    cout<<"\t\tP1";
                }

                if(two==sub[i]&two>0&two<200)
                {
                    cout<<"\t\tP2";
                }

                if(three==sub[i]&three>0&three<200)
                {
                    cout<<"\t\tP3";

                }

                if(four==sub[i]&four>0&four<200)
                {
                    cout<<"\t\tP4";
                }

                if(five==sub[i]&five>0&five<200)
                {
                    cout<<"\t\tP5";
                }

                if(six==sub[i]&six>0&six<200)
                {
                    cout<<"\t\tP6";
                }

                if(seven==sub[i]&seven>0&seven<200)
                {
                    cout<<"\t\tP7";
                }

                if(eieght==sub[i]&eieght>0&eieght<200)
                {
                    cout<<"\t\tP8";
                }
                if(nine==sub[i]&nine>0&nine<200)
                {
                    cout<<"\t\tP9";
                }

                cout<<"\t\t"<<sub[i]<<"\n\n";
            }

        }


              for(int i=0;i<=8;i++)
           {
            if(one==sub[i])
            {
                one=one-cut;
            }
            if(two==sub[i])
            {
                two=two-cut;
            }
            if(three==sub[i])
            {
                three=three-cut;
            }
            if(four==sub[i])
            {
                four=four-cut;
            }

            if(five==sub[i])
            {
                five=five-cut;
            }

            if(six==sub[i])
            {
                six=six-cut;
            }

            if(seven==sub[i])
            {
                seven=seven-cut;
            }

            if(eieght==sub[i])
            {
                eieght=eieght-cut;
            }

            if(nine==sub[i])
            {
                nine=nine-cut;
            }

        }


                for(int i=0;i<=8;i++)
    {
        sub[i]= sub[i]-cut; 
    }


               for(int i=0;i<=8;i++)
    {
        if(sub[i]<=0)
        {
            sub[i]=sub[i+1];
            sub[i+1]=0;
        }
    }

    if(sub[0]<=0)
    {
        sub[0]=IO;
    }
    else if(sub[1]<=0)
    {
        sub[1]=IO;
    }
    else if(sub[2]<=0)
    {
        sub[2]=IO;
    }
    else if(sub[3]<=0)
    {
        sub[3]=IO;
    }
```

Comment: You know that `&` is a bitwise-AND operator, right?

Comment: Yeah I know it's an and operator, but it's working for what I'm trying to do with this program

Comment: No, @juanchopanza is telling you it's *bitwise*, suggesting that you might think it's *logical* (which would be `&&`, not `&`).  They are quite different.  Looking at your code, I'm pretty certain you need the logical operator.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing outside your array here:

```
 for(int i=0;i<=8;i++)
{
    if(sub[i]<=0)
    {
        sub[i]=sub[i+1]; //^^if i =8, then i +1 = 9, array index out of bound
        sub[i+1]=0; //^^same as above
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I see the problem now.

Comment: @Ron The best way to thank somebody for putting the time into answering your question is to give them a vote and/or accept their answer if it helped you.